# Scatter Bubble chart without Y axis in HighChart

Tags: angular, highcharts

As per my project requirement I want to create a Scatter Bubble Chart using highchart and Angular 6 but the twist is that I won't have any Y axis. I have tried everything but have not found a solution. I have added a image so as to clarify my requirement, please refer to it.  [Sample Image for my requirement](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4slNq.png)

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This solution may help you. Just add visible as false in the highchart code like bellow.

```
yAxis: {
        visible:false
  },
```

Reference link https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/yAxis.visible

Comment: This will only make y axis invisible it wont be disabled. If you go through the picture that I have attached you will find that all the bubbles are lying on X axis, they should be very close to the x axis. making y axis invisible wont help here.
Anyways thanks a lot for the suggestion :)

Answer (score 0):

In order to achieve the effect you expecting, you need to set (as @sachin said) `yAxis.visible` parameter equal to false, and all your points need to have `y` equal to the same value. Here is the code and example:

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {

    chart: {
        type: 'bubble',
    },
    title: false,
    legend: {
        enabled: false
    },
    xAxis: {
        type: 'datetime'
    },
    yAxis: {
        visible: false
    },
    series: [{
        pointStart: Date.UTC(2018, 9, 6, 12),
        pointInterval: 15 * 60 * 1000, // 15 mins
        data: [
            {y: 1, z: 10},
            {y: 1, z: 8},
            {y: 1, z: 5},
            {y: 1, z: 10},
            {y: 1, z: 4},
            {y: 1, z: 9},
        ]
    }]

});
```

**Live example:** https://jsfiddle.net/6e9nb3qk/